# How do I write a for loop in Python to repeatedly ask the user to enter a number until they enter in a whole number (0, 1, 2, etc)?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I know how to do this with a while loop and know how to use a for-loop in other languages like Java and C++. I want to use a for-loop in place of where I have written the while loop asking for the user input.

```
# You are required to use for-loop to solve this and round your answer to 2 decimal places. Write
    # a program that takes n ∈ N (i.e., any positive integer including zero) from the user and use the
    # input value to compute the sum of the following series:
    
    n = -1
    while n < 0:
        n = int(input("Enter a value to compute: "))
        # keep asking for user input until a whole number (0, 1, 2, 3, etc...) has been entered
    k = 0
    sum = 0
    # To hold the sum of the fraction to be displayed
    lastTerm = 0
    # This variable represents the last term to be added to the fraction sum before the while loop below terminates
    
    if n == 0:
        sum = 0
    elif n == 1:
        sum = 1
    else:
        while lastTerm != 1 / n:
            lastTerm = (n - k) / (k + 1)
            sum = sum + (n - k) / (k + 1)
            k += 1
    print("{:.2f}".format(sum))
    # Print the sum to two decimal places
```

Comment: You want to use a ```for loop``` instead of ```while``` loop, right?

Comment: yes. That is correct!

Comment: And What will you do of that floating point or negative number entered.

Comment: it is supposed to keep asking the user to "enter a value to compute:" until the user enters a non-negative number. Then it will compute a sum and print that sum.

Comment: Please check out my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use this to check for whole numbers -

```
if num < 0:
   # Not a whole number

elif num >= 0:
   # A whole number
```

**for a `for loop`**:

```
import itertools

for _ in itertools.repeat([]):  # An infinite for loop
    num = input('Enter number : ')
    if num < 0:
       # Not a whole number
       pass # This will ask again
    
    elif num >= 0:
       # A whole number
       break  # break from for loop to continue the program
```

**Easier Way** -

```
mylist = [1]
for i in mylist :  # infinite loop
    num = int(input('Enter number : '))
    if num < 0:
       mylist.append(1)
       pass # This will ask again

    
    elif num >= 0:
       # A whole number
       break
```

Comment: Can this be accomplished with a for loop in python? I have done it with a while loop in python but not a for loop.

Comment: of course write this under the while or for loop

Comment: do this for `for loop`

Comment: that is the trouble I am having translating this from a while loop into a for loop in python.

Comment: You need to import itertools

Comment: that seems unnecessarily more complicated. Perhaps my instructor made a mistake asking us to rewrite our while loops as for loops.

Comment: I will make it easier so wait

Answer (score 1):

One option is to catch the exception which is thrown when you cannot convert the input to an int, i.e.

```
while(True):
    try:
        # read input and try and covert to integer
        n = int(input("Enter a value to compute: "))

        # if we get here we got an int but it may be negative
        if n < 0:
            raise ValueError
        
        # if we get here we have a non-negative integer so exit loop
        break
    # catch any error thrown by int()
    except ValueError:
        print("Entered value was not a postive whole number")
```

Alternative, slightly cleaner but I'm not 100% sure isdigit() will cover all cases

```
while(true):
    n = input("Enter a value to compute: ")
    if value.isdigit():
        break
    else:
        print("Entered value was not a postive whole number")
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this? It uses the `for` loop and sums all the values in the list.

```
x=[1,2,3,4] #== test list to keep the for loop going 
sum_list=[]
for i in x:
    j=float(input("Enter a number: "))
    if not j.is_integer() or j<0:
        sum_list.append(j)
        x.append(1) #=== Add element in list to keep the cyclone going
    else:
        break
sums=sum(sum_list)
print("The Sum of all the numbers is: ",round(sums,2))
```